# install mysql in home directory

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, installation, home-directory

I need to install mysql in home folder, I am using Ubuntu 12.10. I am trying to install it from binary. I gone through some related posts, but I didn't find any useful post to set the mysql in home folder. How can I do it?

Comment: You will have to compile it from sources

Comment: Do you need the mysql server or the client libs. or both?

Answer (score 3):

If you install mysql from source code you can chose the directory adding the right option when you rum the `./configure` command

Here is the guide: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/installing-source-distribution.html
Here are the option http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/source-configuration-options.html

The right command should be `./configure --prefix=mypath`